# SSMS 2008R2 SSRS - Insufficient Permissions

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssms, reporting-services

I have SSMS R2 Standard Edition and I am using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio that came with it. I have Windows 7 Professional. I am reading *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services* by Brian Larson and have reached Chapter 10 on Deploying Reports Using the Report Designer.

I am not sure if the problem I am facing is because I am using SSMS R2.

Instructions

On set of instructions it tells you how deploy a report by using the report designer.

Right clicking chapter 9 properties...

> Type Galactic Delivery Services/Chapter 09 for TargetDataSourceFolder
>   and TargetReportFolder. This is the folder into which the report is
>   going to be deployed.

My TargetURL is `http://**/ReportServer`. So when I right click Chapter09 project entry in the Solution Explorer, and select Deploy I get the following errors

> Error 1 The permissions granted to user '****' are insufficient for
>   performing this operation.

FYI

Data Source Properties
Data Source=**;Initial Catalog=Galactic

What is the procedure to grant permission?

I have tried to use the following references but they didn't help...

- http://www.soheib.com/technical-knowledge/sql-server-2012-reporting-services-uac-user-access-control/
- http://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/category/ssrs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have UAC enabled, try running BIDS with administrator permissions. (Right click on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as administrator")

Are you able to access the Report Manager (http://server/reports/) without problems? And how about http://server/reportserver/ ?

Comment: Yea thats what it was. Run As Administrator on BIDS and it worked. Made a not this time and I never forget it again. Thanks Jamie